# Remove all numbers before in the decimal place in a column of numbers using R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe where one of the columns looks like this:

```
Minutes
1.432
12.345
4.556
1.324
0.657
6.558
```

I want to create a column right next to it where the whole numbers have been subtracted from the numbers. It would look like this:

```
Minutes
0.432
0.345
0.556
0.324
0.657
0.558
```

Is there a way to do this in R code?

Comment: `df$Minutes %% 1`

Answer (score 2):

We can subtract from the integer version

```
with(df1, Minutes - as.integer(Minutes))
#[1] 0.432 0.345 0.556 0.324 0.657 0.558
```

#### Benchmarks

```
library(microbenchmark)
v1 <- rep(df1$Minutes, 1e6)
microbenchmark(akrun = v1 - as.integer(v1), brittenb = v1 %%1, unit = 'relative')
#Unit: relative
#     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#     akrun 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000   100
#  brittenb 1.386245 1.392605 1.290523 1.317515 1.232846 1.437915   100
```

#### data

```
df1 <-  data.frame(Minutes =   c(1.432, 12.345, 4.556, 1.324, 0.657, 6.558))
```

Comment: second solution doesnt work as it gives negative values.

Comment: `floor` or `trunc` would have worked instead of `round`

Answer (score 2):

The comment from brittenb is quite good, just use a [modulo](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Arithmetic.html)

```
R> test_df <- data.frame(Minutes =   c(1.432, 12.345, 4.556, 1.324, 
0.657, 6.558)
R> test_df$Minutes_modulo <- test_df$Minutes %% 1
R> test_df
  Minutes Minutes_modulo
1   1.432          0.432
2  12.345          0.345
3   4.556          0.556
4   1.324          0.324
5   0.657          0.657
6   6.558          0.558
```

From the documentation:

> %% indicates x mod y and %/% indicates integer division. It is guaranteed that x == (x %% y) + y * ( x %/% y ) (up to rounding error) unless y == 0 where the result of %% is NA_integer_ or NaN (depending on the typeof of the arguments), and for non-finite arguments.

Comment: Worth noting that when I ran `microbenchmark::microbenchmark()`, @akrun's answer was about twice as fast on a vector of 1e6 values.

Comment: hmm, 2x is interesting

Comment: Mean of 6.35ms vs 14.36ms on my machine.

Comment: yeah I had pretty similar numbers, that almost might warrant a separate question

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing the responses